# How to add table more table to database if I use EF code-first approach before this and do CRUD operation.?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I created a database in SSMS from an ASP.NET Core Web API project using EF code-first approach which works fine.

Now I need to add one more table to my database and use primary key in my table as foreign key and do CURD operation. or share sites that contain similar examples or youtube links.

Model class:

```
namespace WebApi.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string CNIC { get; set; }

        public string FullName { get; set; }
    }

}
```

there are multiple tables which created after executing "initial migration" and "Update databse"

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUsers",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    UserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    NormalizedUserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    Email = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    NormalizedEmail = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    EmailConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    PasswordHash = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    SecurityStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    PhoneNumber = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    PhoneNumberConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    TwoFactorEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    LockoutEnd = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(nullable: true),
                    LockoutEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    AccessFailedCount = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    Discriminator = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    CNIC = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    FullName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                },
```

I want to use id of above table as foreign key in my table and do CRUD operation.

I do not have any idea how to do this.

Comment: Please edit your question title to describe the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Add new property to the model class of the new table  as the following

```
public string UserId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("UserId")]
public virtual AspNetUsers AspNetUser { get; set; }
```

Comment: its clear to me .but what about the remaining part .i will create a model class and define all property that i need in this table but how to work in api controller.

Comment: Add your model class to the data context

        `public class DataContext : DbContext
        {
          ....
        public virtual DbSet<NewModel> NewmodelSet { get; set; }
        ....
        }`

        In your controller

        `NewModel obj = DataContext.NewmodelSet.Where......`